# File write is only writing one line when I have encrypted multiple lines

Tags: python, file

I am trying to encrypt 1 file and save the encrypted text from the first file into another file. I have it all working besides that it is only writing 1 line into the new file instead of the entire file.

```
file1 = open("passwords-plainText", "r")
for line in file1:
    file2 = open("encryptedfile.txt", "w")
    file2.write(encryptVignere(keyGen(), line))
```

The example file I am using looks like this

```
example
secondexample
new line
this is another new line
```

The output into the new file I am saving to only writes the first line and not the rest of the lines
ie.)

```
tyawakud
```

The file should look like this instead...

```
tyawakud
tqiibwaeeonozp
pttzucfqs
foxnzgjwtmbhnpwhjnapmsfg
```

Comment: Every time you re-open the file, you're rewriting from the beginning.

Comment: Just open it _once_, before your loop starts.

Comment: Or open it in `a` mode to append to the end, instead of `w` mode.

Comment: Okay I feel stupid I should've seen this before. Thank you both

Comment: btw, given the above, it's not the _first_ plaintext line's encrypted counterpart that gets saved, but the _last_ one.

Answer (score 2):

You should only open `file2` once:

```
file1 = open("passwords-plainText", "r")
file2 = open("encryptedfile.txt", "w")

for line in file1:
    file2.write(encryptVignere(keyGen(), line))
```

Otherwise you just keep overwriting it.